# What special features do we *really want* for this site?

Tags: discussion

So now that we are getting ready to graduate to a full site, it's finally time to ask SE if we can have any special site-specific considerations to make the site better. What special feature(s), if any, would be most important to the success and usability of this site?

We've already compiled a kind of [wish list](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/610/599) of features we'd like to see made a part of this site. However we likely won't be able to have everything, so what features do we want *most*? (and why?)

Answer (score 13):

Number one most important.

**Permanent blend file hosting**, integrated like the imgur picture hosting.

---

While some users have taken at upon themselves to make a permanent blend hosting solution, a SE integrated system would be more convenient. Imagine simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (or some other key), and a upload box, like the imgur box, would let you insert a blend right on that page.

A SE integrated system would be more stable, with a much greater chance of staying online (no offense to GCF).

A SE integrated system would have a much greater chance of unifying all blends on one central, permanent location. Instead of the blends we have being scattered across so many different sites with varying levels of security: pasteall, blend-exchange, dropbox, google drive, one drive, filedropper, megashare, github, and many others...

Comment: Might be nice to list some reasons why we'd want this integrated, when we have blend-exchange

Comment: @gandalf3 read edited post.

Comment: @David Offense taken! Because BE has never ever.... crashed..... um.... well... uh

Answer (score 5):

### Automated Header Image Contest

What could be a cooler way to show off what we're all about, then to show off some of our best work at the top of the home page?

This would be run using an automated competition on meta, the highest voted image gets the feature, and then when it's time for the next image, the last one gets retired to a hall of fame.

The time slots would be dependent on the number of entries. It would probably start as a 1 month slot, but come down to something as fast as a week, depending on the amount of participation.

Note, imo [Permanent .blender file hosting](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/what-special-features-do-we-really-want-for-this-site/791#791) is more important.

Comment: I've put a feature request for this [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/783/599)

Answer (score 4):

**searches**

The search seems like it could be fuzzier, and a bit more relaxed about spelling. At the moment it has zero contextual awareness, and fails to find questions that are really about the same thing just asked differently.

**code**

i'd like a better way to share code for answers. Github is fine, but it relies on github being available, and assumes the gists / repo isn't deleted. A blender stackexchange cookbook would get my vote, how much cool code have we shared already?!

Comment: There is syntax highlighting

Comment: @zeffii I was not the one who DVed, but do not take it personal. A DV on the meta is different then on the main site, here a DV shows agreement, or disagreement, so all that means is somebody does not think better code and search is the most important thing.

Comment: These would be nice features indeed, but I imagine they would be implemented already if there was much chance of them being added (if they would be useful *here*, imagine them on SO!).. As you may expect, [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7119/238438) have been [requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/238438) many [times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268318/2730823) on the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38054/238438).

Answer (score 2):

- Community file sharing + contribution functionality. The idea of a community project has been bouncing around for a while now. It'd likely be linked to reputation, like +10 for contributing a prop or model (reward given only once per user, to be fair,) +25 for item being accepted (which can be given out multiple times per user.)
- Permanent file hosting (Dropbox, Google Drive, Github... heck, I'll even take a site that a community member makes from scratch for that purpose!)
- An actual banner that we can link to from other sites
- A small update to the submission form for questions and such, where they show the order of things like bold and italic tags.
- Not being ostracized for simply asking for community input on a question/topic.